# Detectar cuando se ha abierto la misma ventana como en WhatsApp web

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una plataforma web creada con php en backend y javascript en frontend, hay un archivo llamado configs.php, donde solo pueden acceder los administradores (controlado mediante sesiones de php), el problema es que cuando dos administradores acceden al mismo tiempo, pueden producirse errores catastróficos. La idea es que solo un administrador acceda a configs.php a la vez.

Entonces necesito detectar cuándo dos usuarios (administradores) han accedido a esa misma sección (configs.php), o incluso cuando el mismo usuario ha abierto dos ventanas de esa misma sección. En caso de que esto se detecte, lanzar una alerta que impida que configs.php sea usado en más de una ventana a la vez.

Un ejemplo de lo que necesito lograr pueden verlo en web.whatsapp.com, donde si duplican la ventana en la que están, en la primera ventana que tenían abierta les aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces necesito lograr eso con las tecnologías que estoy usando, tal vez se pueda con javascript, o quizá solo pueda hacerse con php y la base de datos (MySQL).

Acepto soluciones con Firebase Realtime Database, ya que también la uso en esta plataforma y podría implementarla.

**EDIT**

No he puesto código porque lo principal que busco con esta pregunta es saber si las tecnologías que estoy usando me permitirán lograrlo, además de estar abierto a otras posibilidades, como bien ya han respondido algunos usuarios.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Crea una tabla con 3 columnas

**indice -- INT AI
url   -- varchar 
id_admin -- INT**

- Cada vez que un admin ingrese a una pagina realiza la consulta para
     ver si la url esta en el listado.
- si la url esta en el listado entonces averigua si id_admin esta en
  cero

  - si esta en cero actualiza la pagina y permite que el admin la vea y
    manipule
  - siempre ten una consulta que averigüe y compare el id del usuario
    activo con el id_admin
  - Si al ingresar el valor de id_admin es diferente a cero entonces no
    permitas que ese nuevo admin vea la pagina, redireccionalo con
    javascript o como prefieras.

No se si la idea es clara, con esto no permitirás que mas de 1 ID vea la pagina al tiempo.

NOTA: recuerda pasar a cero el ID_ADMIN cuando el usuario cierre sesión o cambie de pagina.

Comment: Por lo menos entendí la idea central, me parece una buena opción, pero tal vez no sea seguro pasar a cero el ID_ADMIN cuando el usuario cierre la ventana por un apagón repentino de su equipo. O cuando simplemente no la cierre y se quede AFK. ¿Crees que esas sean limitantes? Pero definitivamente estaré intentando este método pues me parece viable.

Comment: si quieres que eso no pase ya puede mezclar esa solución con un websocket para saber si el usuario se desconecto por accidente.  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas con [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) es muy sencillo de implementar solo te registras y te lleva de la mano en la implementación.

Una vez implementado lo que necesitas controlar son los "[Client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events)".

La idea con pusher basicamente es crear un canal desde el Frontend(Javascript) y escuchar los eventos de los clientes que se conecten, al conectarse puedes validar si ya existe otro conectado y asi restringir el acceso.

Saludos!.

Comment: Gracias, estaré investigando sobre Pusher